# How can I remove custom spending cap on Metamask?

Tags: web3js, erc-20, metamask, erc-20-approve

When I call the approve function of the ERC20 token standard, it asks me to set a custom spending cap, as shown below.

[image]

But I need to use the default value every time without clicking "use default." It should always recognize "use default" as default method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, you cannot for good reason.

Find your answer [here](https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/6055177143579-How-to-customize-token-approvals-with-a-spending-cap).

> We designed this interface to give you more control and visibility over your token allowances, since you'll be prompted to always input a preferred limit, rather than default to the amount proposed by the dapp (though you can still select this default allowance if you choose).

Comment: What if I want to modify this value?